# Fast substitution of chosen entries of matrix in R

Tags: r, vectorization

Fast way for substitution of matrix entries :

```
   # I would like to set values of (1,1) and (2,2) entries of `m` matrix to 3,  
   # obviously below code 
   # replaces also values in (1,2) and (2,1) also, is the is way to replace 
   # entries in proper way without using for()
        m <- matrix(0,5,3)
        m[1:2,1:2] <- 1
#>m
#     [,1] [,2] [,3]
#[1,]    1    1    0
#[2,]    1    1    0
#[3,]    0    0    0
#[4,]    0    0    0
#[5,]    0    0    0
```

It should be possible, as we can treat `matrix` as `vector` and use vector notation on matrix object `matrix[]` instead of matrix notation `matrix[,]`

Comment: what about `m[c(1,7)] <- 1`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve it by `m[matrix(c(1,2,1,2),ncol=2)] <- 1`

The same thing in the expanded form:

```
m.subset <- matrix(c(1,2,1,2),ncol=2)
#     [,1] [,2]
#[1,]    1    1
#[2,]    2    2

m[m.subset] <- 1
#     [,1] [,2] [,3]
#[1,]    1    0    0
#[2,]    0    1    0
#[3,]    0    0    0
#[4,]    0    0    0
#[5,]    0    0    0
```